# Data taken from mysql display division if the date by day is changed

Tags: php, mysql

Currently I have this code that takes data from mysql and displays it as text and tried to make a underline like bar if the date by day is changed, currently with no luck

The first picture shows what this code actually does and the second one what I'm trying to do.
I tried to check if the current date is different from the new one with no luck.

How do I detect the date change with the current code, so that I can make a break between the same day for easy viewing?
[image]

```
<?php
chdir(__DIR__);

error_reporting(E_STRICT | E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', TRUE);


require_once 'config.php';

$mysqli = new mysqli($server, $db_user, $db_password, $database);

if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}   



$sql_list = "SELECT date, name, quantity, 0 as price, 'Download' as Source FROM downloads union all SELECT date, name, quantity, price, 'Sale' as Source FROM sales ORDER BY(`Date`) DESC";


$result_list = $mysqli->query($sql_list);

$ans_lists = array();
while($row = $result_list->fetch_assoc()){
        $source =$row["Source"];
        $name = $row["name"];

        if (stripos($source, "Sale") !== false) {
            $price = $row["price"] ."$";
        }else{
            $price = "";
        }

        $date_str = strtotime($row["date"]);
        $year = date('Y', $date_str);
        $month = date('m', $date_str);
        $day = date('d', $date_str);
        $hour = date('H', $date_str);
        $minute = date('i', $date_str);




        $ans_list = "" . sprintf('%s-%s-%s %s:%s',$year,$month,$day,$hour,$minute) . ", " .  $name . " - " .  $source . " Added " . $price . "";
        //echo $ans_list;
        $ans_lists[] = $ans_list;
}



$count = 0;
$max_lines = 1000;    

foreach($ans_lists as $f){

    if ($count >= $max_lines){
        break;
    }

    if (stripos($f, "Sale") !== false) {
        $class = "sales";
        $text = "text-sales";

        if (preg_match("/(CRCV2)/i", $f)) {
                $squaresales = "crcv2-sales";
        }else if(preg_match("/(CRC12)/i", $f)){
                $squaresales = "crc12-sales";
        }

    }
    else{
        $class = "row";
        $square = "general";
        $text = "text-general";
        $squaresales = "";

    }

    if (preg_match("/(CRCV2|CRCPV2-01|CRCPV2-02|CRCPV2-03|CRCPV2-04|CRCPV2-05|CRCPV2-06|CRCPV2-07|CRCPV2-08|CRCPV2-09|CRCPV2-10|CRCPV2-11|CRCPV2-12)/i", $f)) {
            $square = "crcv2";
    }else if(preg_match("/(CRC12|CRCP01|CRCP02|CRCP03|CRCP04|CRCP05|CRCP06|CRCP07|CRCP08|CRCP09|CRCP10|CRCP11|CRCP12|CRCP13|CRCP14)/i", $f)){
            $square = "crc12";
    }

$count++;
    echo "<div class='".$class." scale'><a class='".$square."'></a><a class='".$squaresales."'></a><a class='".$text."'>".$f."</a></div>\r\n";
}

$mysqli->close();
```

[image]

Comment: I am not sure what the question is.

Comment: How do I detect the date change with the current code, so that I can make a break between the same day for easy viewing

Comment: you can store past data date and compare with the current data date. When are different include a break

Comment: Tried that it displays the same first date for all of them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing your `$ans_lists[] = $ans_list` to something like this:

```
// Here youll get something like 20150708
$ymd_date = date( 'Ymd', strtotime($row["date"]) );

// Prepare array for results by day
if ( !isset( $ans_lists[$ymd_date] ) ) {
    $ans_lists[$ymd_date] = array();
}

// Add result to specific date
$ans_lists[$ymd_date][] = $ans_list;
```

And then change `foreach($ans_lists as $f){` iterator to

```
foreach($ans_lists as $ymd_date => $array_of_entries){
    foreach($array_of_entries as $f){
         // ... here stays your printing logic
         // ...
    }
    // Here ends one specific day
    // so you can output breakline here or something
    echo '<hr>';
}
```

Comment: Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /var/www/logtest.php that's on foreach($array_of_entries as $f){}